# Comma doesn't seem to find "Legacy extensions" for some modules

Tags: raku, commaide

I’m trying to figure out how to use the feature for automatically update legacy extensions with the Comma IDE. It either behaves inconsistently or I'm not understanding something clearly. I used Comma as recently as last week to generate a patch for the [XDG::BaseDirectory](https://raku.land/zef:jonathanstowe/XDG::BaseDirectory) module for updating the legacy extensions. It worked fine.

Yesterday, I downloaded the [spit](https://raku.land/github:spitsh/Spit) module.

I opened the module in a new project in Comma CP, v2022.10.

With the project open, I click Tools -> Update file extensions.

I get a “No legacy extensions detected” message.

However, the module is full of files with .pm6 and .t extensions.

I’m not sure what it is about the “spit” module that prevents it from working. I also tried it with another module, Router::Boost, and ran into the same problem. I also tried with the latest version of Comma CT and ran into the same problem. Finally, I tried fiddling with some properties in the META6.json file to get it working but had no luck with that, either.

Anyone know how I can get this feature working again?

Comment: Any reason not to accept your answer?

Answer (score 4):

OK, this has been solved.

When opening a downloaded distro for the first time, **DO NOT** do "File -> New -> Project".

Instead, use **"File -> New -> Project from existing source."**